# How can I install the latest libxml2 on Mac 10.6 using Fink?

Tags: mac, fink

I have installed fink, but when I type:

```
fink list
```

then libxml2 (or any libxml package) is not found in the list. It's clearly there in the library on the fink site. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run:

```
fink selfupdate
```

and that refreshed me with the full list of libraries so that I was able to install what I wanted.